# How to properly extract data from JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am learning AJAX and I am having some difficulties in getting the result when I use it in MVC example.

My code has the following parts:

1- MVC Controller: there is a method just return one value:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DemoAjaxMvc()
    {
        return Json(new { returnedData = "Hello" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
    }
```

2- The JavaScript part:

```
function testAjax(){
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "DemoAjaxMvc",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
              //
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));

              alert(data.length);

              alert(data[0].returnedData);
          },
          error: function (exception) {                
              console.log(exception);
          }
      });
}
```

3- The View part:

```
<button type="button" onclick="testAjax()">Show Returned Data</button>
```

What I couldn't understand is that the code is actually able to read the data from `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` but `alert(data.length);` always return `undefined` and the `alert(data[0].returnedData);` returns an error

How can I successfully extract the `returnedData` from the `JSON.stringify(data)`?

I found some questions with almost the same title as my question, but I could not understand them because they seem different and I am not yet familiar with how to read the code properly

Comment: The is how the result looks like from the **JSON.stringify**: `{"returnedData":"Hello"}`

Comment: try alert(JSON.stringify(data.length));

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the stringify.  `dataType: 'json'` is telling jQuery that the response should be JSON, and it will auto parse it into an object for you.  All you have to do at that point should be to access it like any normal object.

```
console.log(data.returnedData); //this according to your code should be "Hello"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I thought I need to put the [0] with the data to be like `data[0]`

Comment: No, once the data gets to javascript, it's all javascript.  At that point it's the same object or array access as you would expect.  In your case, you are not returning a json encoded array.

Comment: @Tapiar Understood. Thanks!